# At which stage of compiling is "symbol defined multiple times" be reported?

Tags: c

When compile and run, which stages can report error "symbol defined multiple times"?

Preprocessor, Compiler, Assembler, Linker, Executable?

Comment: Is this a question from a test?

Comment: At least 3 of those can be trivially ruled out.. in any case, when faced with such question, justify yes/no for each of the choices and make a strong argument for why such is held. Then test/confirm the hypothesis and go back and change the assumptions as required until a final proposed answer is reached. (Such questions are *terrible* without initial justifications, IMOHO.)

Comment: When you read the part of someone else's lecture notes from the session you missed while nursing your labor-day hang-over.

Comment: @user2864740: I would argue that only two can be *trivially* ruled out.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Okay, then rule out 1 and 2 (where a number does not correspond to item order) trivially and make arguments why 3 and 4 are suspect and why 5 is most likely and/or must be included anyway - the process is not directed at you, of course :)

Comment: How are there 3 answers to this one question???

Comment: By definition a "stage of compiling" can only be in the "compiler" stage. (If you don't agree, then don't have a stage called "compiler").

Comment: @Kaz: It is not unheard of that ones says that one "compiles" a program when running `make`. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since answers with differing opinions have cropped up, I guess I should contribute mine as well.

I'd argue the answer is slightly dependent on just how strictly you want to define "symbols". If the definition only includes entries in the symbol table, the answer would be the linker and the assembler; the linker when it tries to link multiple object files which contain the same symbol, and the assembler when it tries to produce a symbol table from an assembly source that tries to create the same symbol twice.

If one also includes in the definition the source code constructs that generate symbols, rather than the symbols themselves (which would be reasonable), then the compiler would also have to be included, since it is at liberty to (and almost invariably does) error out on multiple definitions that would result in the same symbol. I think a C compiler would usually phrase the resulting error with "multiple definitions" rather than "multiple symbols", however. So it's a matter of definition.

I would argue, then, that the answer should be "compiler, assembler and linker".

Answer (score 1):

This is sad... To save you from any more humiliation, I'm gonna just give you the answer.  It's the linker.

Comment: I have to +1 this just to quell the guilt from my contribution to the gauntlet.

Comment: This is wrong, though. (Or incomplete, at least, if you will.)

Comment: @Dolda2000 maybe, it depends on your compiler.  The linking phase is the only phase at which the compiler is *required* to report it as an error.

Comment: @randomusername and in fact, both in preprocessor and source-compilation, I've only ever seen it emit as a warning. Source compilation will error with an "already *declared*" message, and warn on scope-hiding, and of course the cpp could warn on macro definition, and there I've never seen this as an error. In short, the linker is the only place I've seen anything close to that *specific* message; the remainder require suspending disbelief to a degree. (of course the execuable at runtime could just `printf` the message, lest we leave that possibility out to complete the arguing for no reason).

Comment: @WhozCraig: GNU `as` certainly has this to say: `test.s:12: Error: symbol 'a' is already defined`, and `gcc` certainly flags multiple definitions as an error, rather than a warning.

Comment: @Dolda2000 shows how often I kick off my nasm compiler with bad code. (or for that matter, how often my C/C++ toolchain do it for me). And what is the gcc *actual* error message? (I don't have it handy, only clang, sry).

Comment: What was the -1 for?

Comment: @WhozCraig: It says `error: redefinition of ‘a’`.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Really? Curious what gcc you're using, [as coliru disagrees](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7636fb4073110456) (love that site).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Locals are a different thing, as they are, indeed, declared rather than defined. "Defining", in C, usually means outputting object section data, which locals do not do. See [this coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a345c522c155f4a4) instead.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Ah, that makes sense. As much as any of this anyway. Thanks. I now wonder if it does the same reporting for global variables as it does functions. I'll have to check, but my horrid commute beckons me. Take care.

Comment: @WhozCraig: [It does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4bca8c4882794689), which makes sense since they produce `.data` section contents.

Answer (score 1):

Every stage that uses symbolic names can report this error:

- Preprocessor will report redefinitions of macros,
- Compiler will report redefinitions of locals, fields in `struct`s, and static symbols in outer scope,
- Linker will report redefinitions of external functions and variables.

Comment: While this isn't *wrong*, I'd argue that "symbol" has a more commonly understood meaning that would not include preprocessor macros or `struct` fields. What I refer to, of course, is those symbols which are in the object-file symbol tables (and, arguably, the source code constructs which produce them).

Comment: @Dolda2000 The term "preprocessor symbol" is not unheard of. Google for it.

Comment: @Kaz: Sure, it's not unheard of. I'm just saying that "symbol", when used otherwise unqualified in these contexts, usually refers to symbol-table symbols. If this actually is a question on a test, I cannot imagine the preprocessor being a valid answer.